# Hide All Warnings in Terminal of Visual Studio Code for React-Native Code

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find away to disable all yellow-colored warnings from my react-native app in the terminal of Visual Studio Code. I am aware of LogBox, but this seems to be for the app itself, not the IDE. Right now not only are yellow warnings getting in the way of what I'm trying to log to the console, but the same warning is printing to the terminal multiple times. How can I simply disable the printing of warnings from react-native in the terminal of Visual Studio Code?

Below is an example of the warnings that print multiple times in the VSC terminal. I just want to hide these altogether.

```
It appears that you are using old version of react-navigation library. Please update @react-navigation/bottom-tabs, @react-navigation/stack and @react-navigation/drawer to version 5.10.0 or above to take full advantage of new functionality added to react-native-screens
at node_modules/react-native-screens/src/index.native.tsx:141:8 in Screen#render
at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

It appears that you are using old version of react-navigation library. Please update @react-navigation/bottom-tabs, @react-navigation/stack and @react-navigation/drawer to version 5.10.0 or above to take full advantage of new functionality added to react-native-screens
at node_modules/react-native-screens/src/index.native.tsx:141:8 in Screen#render
at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, in your App.js:

```
import { LogBox } from "react-native";
        
export default function App() {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs([
        "It appears that you are using old version of react-navigation library",
      ]);
      // ... the rest of your code ...
}
```

Note: With the following method you should be able to ignore all logs but for some reason this didn't work for me, but you should give it a try:

```
  LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(true);
```

Source: [SDK 40 react-native-screens warning if using react-navigation v4](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/11301)

Also read: [YellowBox has been replaced with LogBox. Please call LogBox.ignoreLogs() instead.](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10276)

Comment: Thanks. That worked. It is strange that the `ignoreAllLogs` doesn't work though.

Comment: Also, strangely, this works for some messages, but not all. Some of those I included in the array don't get caught,  whereas others do.

Comment: Im having same issue, any idea on resolution?